# Undefined variable problem on Laravel 9.x

Tags: php, laravel

I'm trying to get a my title variable from my control page and display it on the about page.

I don't think I have a typo, but it might me. I'm not sure.

Here is my control page code;

```
class PagesController extends Controller
{
    public function index(){
        $title = 'Welcome to Laravel';
        return view ('pages.index')->with('title', $title);
    }
    public function about(){
        $title = 'About us';
        return view ('pages.about')->with('title', $title);
    }
    public function services(){
        $title = 'The services';
        return view ('pages.services')->with('title', $title);
    }
}
```

In this page, the index and services functions work fine, but I can't get the about page.

Here is my display pages;

```
This is Index page

@extends('layouts.app')
@section('content')
    <h1>{{$title}}</h1>
    <p>This is the Laravel Application</p>
 @endsection
```

This is the *about* page:

```
@extends('layouts.app')
@section('content')
<h1>{{$title}}</h1>
<p>This is the About page</p>
@endsection
```

[The error I have](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nN90s.png)

Comment: can you try  return view ('pages.about', ['title' => $title])

Comment: try `php artisan cache:clear`

Comment: The code you shared works perfectly

Comment: @Mike I tired that but nothing happened. Then I cleared my cache as medilies metioned it. But nothing changed again.

Comment: I also tried on different browser too... It's really weird.

Comment: `php artisan cache:clear` and `php artisan view:clear` didn't worked either.

Comment: The syntax highlighting is off for the last part. Is there a solution? E.g. to `lang-html`? Or should it be turned off?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since this is a test application from a lesson, I forgot to delete some extra code in my route file.

This is my route file:

```
Route::get('/', 'App\Http\Controllers\PagesController@index');
Route::get('/about', 'App\Http\Controllers\PagesController@about');
Route::get('/services', 'App\Http\Controllers\PagesController@services');

The commented area shouldn't be here. That was the whole problem over here...
// Route::get('/about', function(){
//     return view ('pages.about');
// });
```

Comment: Please, edit your question in order to add more details.

Comment: Please read "[answer]". It helps more if you supply an explanation why this is the preferred solution and explain how it works. We want to educate, not just provide code.

Answer (score 0):

Do this:

```
 return view ('pages.index', compact('title'));
```

or:

```
return view ('pages.index', [
   'title' => $title
]);
```

Comment: Thank you for your effort but it didn't worked again... The weird thing is I used those functions for index and services , and they worked with no problem at all...

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

Since you are returning just the title, there isn't any need to call any verbs. Rather you should directly call the view:

```
route::view('/about', 'Pagecontroller@about');
```

or

pass the parameter by *compact*:

```
 return view ('pages.index', compact('title'));
```

or

```
return view ('pages.index', ['title' => $title]);
```

Comment: Thank you for your advice. One more thing, is it bad/wrong/outdated to use the way I did? Sorry to bother I'm just trying to learn the fundamentals.

Answer (score -1):

This form of passing variables is a short-lived entry of a variable into the session. Then accessing the variable on the page should look like this:

```
{{ session('title') }}
```

If you want to pass data to the view, then you need to use the method

```
return view('pages.services', ['title' => $title]);
```

[Laravel views](https://laravel.com/docs/9.x/views)